# VBS: oShell.run and robocopy not working

Tags: vbscript, robocopy

I'm trying to mirror a share to a local computer using VBS and robocopy. The script works, but the folder from the share has spaces in the path and I can't get it to work with a path with spaces.

```
InputFile = "\\baardrob\Software application\Scripts\Input\computers.Txt"
Const OverWriteFiles = True
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile("\\baardrob\Software application\Scripts\Input\failed.txt", 2)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
  On Error Resume Next
  oShell.run "robocopy "\\baardrob\software application" c:\temps /mir"  
  If Err Then myLog.WriteLine strComputer
  On Error Goto 0
Loop
myLog.Close

MsgBox "Done"
```

EDIT: 
Ekkehard.Horner solution worked, I have another problem though. c:\temps was just a attempt to get it work, it should actually be writing to "\" & strComputer  "\c$", but this doesn't work.

I allready tried:

```
InputFile = "\\baardrob\Software application\Scripts\Input\computers.Txt"
Const OverWriteFiles = True
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile("\\baardrob\Software application\Scripts\Input\failed.txt", 2)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
  On Error Resume Next
  oShell.run "robocopy ""\\baardrob\Software application""  ""\\"" & strComputer & ""\c$"" /mir" 
  If Err Then myLog.WriteLine strComputer
  On Error Goto 0
Loop
myLog.Close

MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficient error description. Have `robocopy` write a log (`/log:C:\path\to\your.log`) and see what error you get. Also note that you need admin privileges to be able to access administrative shares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
"robocopy "\\baardrob\software application" c:\temps /mir"
```

is not valid VBScript:

```
>> s = "robocopy "\\baardrob\software application" c:\temps /mir"
>>
Error Number:       1002
Error Description:  Syntax error
```

Fix 'inner' quotes by escaping them using "" (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28088558/603855)):

```
>> s = "robocopy ""\\baardrob\software application"" c:\temps /mir"
>> WScript.Echo s
>>
robocopy "\\baardrob\software application" c:\temps /mir
```

**Update wrt to augmented question:**

```
>> strComputer = "pipapo"
>> s = "robocopy ""\\baardrob\Software application""  ""\\"" & strComputer & ""\c$"" /mir"
>> WScript.Echo s
>>
robocopy "\\baardrob\Software application"  "\\" & strComputer & "\c$" /mir
>> s = "robocopy ""\\baardrob\Software application""  ""\\" & strComputer & "\c$"" /mir"
>> WScript.Echo s
>>
robocopy "\\baardrob\Software application"  "\\pipapo\c$" /mir
```

Comment: Thanks worked, though still  have some problems, I have edited my original question,

Comment: It works, just 1 more thing. When the remote computer isn't online, robocopy still try's copy each folder, I rather have it go to the next computer from input file "computers.txt" and write to a log "failed.txt".